# PyQt - QScrollArea moves widget down to viewport when layout is updated while scrolled down

Tags: python, qwidget, pyqt6, qscrollarea

I have a custom widget that is a table consisting of a `QGridLayout` inside a `QScrollArea`. You can place widgets into the cells. I also placed `QScrollArea` s as headers in the margins of the table. When I scroll the table the headers also scroll. This is the result. I coloured the headers' widgets in blue and the headers' scroll areas in red.

[image: Table]

You can add or remove rows and columns to the table's model and then the whole table and its headers is updated. If I scroll down and want to e.g. place a new row under the selected cell the table displays the changes without any problems. But the respective header's widget is moved down into the viewport of its scroll area so that the numbers doesn't line up with the grid anymore but the widget is aligned with the viewport. When you then scroll up there is a big gap between the header's widget and the top of the scroll area. It looks like this:

[image: Misaligned headers]

This is a problem with both headers. Each header section is a `QWidget` with a `QLabel` inside. The model is a list with all header sections. To summerize, when a header readds the sections to its layout it always begins within the visible area to the user.

Here is the code:

**UI_Header.py** (UI only)

```
class Header(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self, direction: QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction, parent: QtWidgets.QWidget | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")

        self.header_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.header_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue")
        self.header_widget.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)  
        self.header_layout = QtWidgets.QBoxLayout(direction)
        self.header_layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.header_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.header_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        self.header_widget.setLayout(self.header_layout)
        self.setWidget(self.header_widget)

        if direction == QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction.LeftToRight:
            self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
            self.header_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft)
        else:
            self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
            self.header_layout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
```

**header.py** (Controll of the ui.)

```
class HeaderView(Header):
    itemResized = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, direction: QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction, parent: QtWidgets.QWidget | None = ...) -> None:
        super().__init__(direction, parent)
        self.orientation = orientation
        self.direction = direction
        self.model = None


    def clear(self) -> None:
        for i in reversed(range(self.header_layout.count())):
            w = self.header_layout.takeAt(i).widget()
            self.header_layout.removeWidget(w)

    def update_header(self) -> None:
        self.clear()
        for i, hitem in enumerate(self.model.header(self.orientation)):
            hitem.resized.connect(self.itemResized.emit)
            hitem.isResizing.connect(self.set_resizing)
            if not hitem.model.text or hitem.model.orientation == QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
                hitem.label.setText(str(i+1))
            self.header_layout.addWidget(hitem)
        self.header_widget.updateGeometry()
```

You can see that when the model changes the every section "item" is removed from the layout and added to the layout again according to the model. I know this is not the most efficient way to update this.

This is how the headers are placed into the table-widget:

**UI_Table.py**

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setUi()
        self.setObjectName("Table")
        self.setStyleSheet(fromStyle("Table"))
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)       
    
    def setUi(self):
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.grid_widget = GridWidget(self)
        self.grid_widget.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)  
        self.grid_widget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 0, 0)
        self.grid.setSpacing(0)
        self.grid.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.grid_widget.setLayout(self.grid)
        self.setWidget(self.grid_widget)

        self.margins = QtCore.QMargins(30, 30, 0, 0)
        self.setViewportMargins(self.margins)

        self.hheaders = HeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Horizontal, QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction.LeftToRight, self)
        self.vheaders = HeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Orientation.Vertical, QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction.TopToBottom, self)


    def scrollContentsBy(self, dx: int, dy: int) -> None:
        self.hheaders.scroll(dx, 0)
        self.vheaders.scroll(0, dy)
        self.updateGeometry()
        super().scrollContentsBy(dx, dy)

    def resizeEvent(self, a0: QtGui.QResizeEvent | None) -> None:
        rect = self.viewport().geometry()
        self.hheaders.setGeometry(
            rect.x() +1, rect.y() - self.margins.top(), rect.width(), self.margins.top()
        )
        self.vheaders.setGeometry(
            rect.x()  - self.margins.left(), rect.y() + 1, self.margins.left(), rect.height()
        )
        super().resizeEvent(a0)
```

As you can see I used `updateGeometry()` after the headers are updated. There was a scenario where this worked although there was the caveat that the table scrolled to the top position but I couldn't replicate this behavior.

I also set the alignment on the scroll areas itselves and not only on their layouts but that also didn't work. I also tried to use a `QGridLayout` like in the table's layout because it doesn't have the problem. I have a guess that it may have to do how the headers' geometry is set in the table's `resizeEvent()` because the table grid works fine with this way of updating but I don't know how to place the headers in the margins otherwise.

So I ran out if ideas and I hope that someone has an idea to fix the problem with the scrolling areas of the headers whenever they are updated. Tell me if you need more code to replicate but my project is really big so I can't include everything. I am thankful for every idea.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to recreate some sort of QTableView on your own, but I really don't understand why. I may assume that you're doing this for learning purposes, but I'd like to know what you're trying to learn with this, since your approach is only vaguely similar to that of a QTableView and abstract item views in general, which have much more extended features and reliable implementation aspects. Most importantly, they are based on QAbstractScrollArea, which doesn't have certain limitations QScrollArea has, allowing for better flexibility. So, why you're doing this?

Comment: In any case, if you want help with this, please provide a valid [mre] (and within a single code block), since your current code is missing classes and functions, and without them we cannot recreate the problem, nor understand it (and, therefore, we cannot answer you).

Comment: @musicamante As I said I want to place widgets into the cells which have different functions like text editing, image viewing or a mini audio player and for this purpose QTableView is not suitable. It's not a table to just show simple data.

Comment: While displaying data is the main purpose of an item view, it's not the only one. In fact, it's quite common to use the default views (especially QTableView and QTableWidget) just as some sort of "advanced layout manager", since it provides headers, resizing features and intuitive access. You can set *any* widget in each cell, just by using `setIndexWidget()` (or `setItemWidget()` in QTableWidget) for simple situations, or implement your own delegates that will provide editor widgets, which is normally a preferred choice since it also allows automatic linking of model data with editors.

Comment: I suggest you to explain exactly *why* you think QTableView/Widget isn't suitable for what you need, because I'm under the impression that you are having an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is trying to find the wrong (and, usually, unnecessarily more complex) solution for the wrong problem. We may be able to answer your doubts about all that and tell you the *proper* way to achieve what you need: it won't actually answer *this* question, but it's also unlikely that anybody would find this approach (and its solution) useful, including you.

Comment: @musicamante I tried "QTableView" out and put the widgets into the cells but then problems displaying the widgets appeared e.g. when scrolling. The other downside is QHeaderView which doesn't allow me to adjust the minimum size of the sections individually.
The thing is that the documentation doesn't reccomend to put widgets into the cells and I've already made a question on this platform what would be the best way to realize a table like this and the recommendation was to build a custom widget.

Comment: The scrolling problem could be caused by wrong usage of the functions (including parent definitions), while you can set the minimum size by properly using the QHeaderView signals. I strongly recommend you to avoid this convoluted approach, as it's possible it will create further issues in the future, and, as said, it's done for the wrong reasons. I instead suggest you to create a new question by pointing out the issues you're having by using a normal QTableView (but, for what you need, a QTableWidget may suffice) for your needs, and provide a valid [mre] (in a single code block).

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the solution by myself. These are the changes I made:

**UI_Header.py:**

First I enabled the scrollbars again and made them invisible with the stylesheet. Also the size policy setting is unnecessary.

```
class Header(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    
    def __init__(self, direction: QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.Direction, parent: QtWidgets.QWidget | None = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.verticalScrollBar().setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {height:0px;}")
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setStyleSheet("QScrollBar {width:0px;}")
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red")
        ...
```

**UI_Table.py**

Instead of using the `scroll()` method I connected the scrollbars of the table to the scrollbars of the headers. This will ensure that the scrolling position of the table and the headers always matches. These are the additons. I don't use the method `scrollContentsBy()` anymore. Also in the `on_resized()` method I changed the code so the header_widget is being resized. Before that the scrollbars wouldn't work because I resized the scroll area.

```
class Table(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setUi()
        self.setObjectName("Table")
        self.setStyleSheet(fromStyle("Table"))
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)       
    
    def setUi(self):
        ...
        self.horizontalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.on_scroll_bar_moved)
        self.verticalScrollBar().valueChanged.connect(self.on_scroll_bar_moved)

    def on_scroll_bar_moved(self) -> None:
        self.hheaders.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value())
        self.vheaders.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value())

    def on_resized(self) -> None:
        self.hheaders.header_widget.setMinimumWidth(self.grid_widget.width())
        self.vheaders.header_widget.setMinimumHeight(self.grid_widget.height())
```

**table.py**

The misalignment still happened but now I just needed to set the headers' scroll bars values to the scroll bar values of the table. This happens after the table is updated.

```
class WidgetTable(Table):

    def clear(self) -> None:
        """Removes all rows and columns."""
        for i in reversed(range(self.grid.count())):
            w = self.grid.takeAt(i).widget()
            self.grid.removeWidget(w)

    def updateTable(self) -> None:
        """Updates table according to the model."""
        self.clear()
        self.vheaders.verticalScrollBar().setValue(0)
        self.hheaders.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(0)
        for irow in range(self.model.row_count()):
            for icolumn in range(self.model.column_count()):
                cell = self.model.data(irow, icolumn)
                self.grid.addWidget(cell, irow, icolumn)

        ...

        self.hheaders.horizontalScrollBar().setMaximum(self.horizontalScrollBar().maximum())
        self.vheaders.verticalScrollBar().setMaximum(self.verticalScrollBar().maximum())
        self.hheaders.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(self.horizontalScrollBar().value())
        self.vheaders.verticalScrollBar().setValue(self.verticalScrollBar().value())
```

Maybe there is a better way but this is the solution for now. There is still some minor misalignment but this can be solved by adjusting spacing and the margins.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't seem effective, especially if you're actually showing scrollbars in the headers too. I can spot other issues, and there're probably more (other than those you already point out), but it's impossible to help you in any way unless a valid [mre] is provided to the question (which, as said, is missing aspects that prevent us to actually *try* your code). I still believe that your approach is unnecessary for what you actually need, since you're looking for solutions to complex issues that are not caused by the *real* problem (your ability to add widgets to a QTableView), while »

Comment: »you're trying to "reinvent the wheel" and in that process you're forced to find workarounds (that don't really work as expected and introduce further problems) to issues that probably wouldn't exist in the first place. I warmly suggest you to create a question about the real problem instead, with a proper explanation of the issues you're facing and a valid MRE. That question (and its possible answers) might also be much more useful to others than this is, which represents a use-case scenario that would be unlikely met by anybody else, mostly because the real reason behind all this is unknown.